# how to reference the fields in json returned from api?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to download two values ​​via api and use them in the header of the web page.

the api call works and return a json and the format is valid.

I've tried
var tvotes = jsonstr.totvotes;

and
var tvotes = jsonstr ["totvotes"];
but gets the error undefined

what am I doing wrong? - how do I reference the fields in jsonstr?

Thanks in advance

Michael

This is the my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script>
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://au2mailer.com/api/a2m-getreviews.asp?apikey={{API_KEY}}');
        request.send();
        request.onload = ()=>{
        var jsonstr = request.response;
        document.write(jsonstr);
        document.write(jsonstr.totvotes);
        }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to decode JSON first with JSON.parse(response)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your api you're requesting here is pretty weird. It doesn't return the json as pure string but instead a html text containing the json string.

After understanding that, you can use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to read the html text in and extract the body content with ease.
Then you got the json string. After that you still need to parse the json string to an actual object, otherwise you try to get attributes of a string. To parse the string you can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

I updated your question to fit this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script>
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://au2mailer.com/api/a2m-getreviews.asp?apikey={{apikey}}');
        request.send();
        request.onload = ()=>{
          var receivedDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(request.response, "text/html");
          var jsonstr = receivedDom.body.innerText;
          var parsedstr = JSON.parse(jsonstr);
          document.write(parsedstr.totvotes);
        }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I also saw you're using the XMLHttpRequest. It still works though but it's not that convenient really. I would use the modern way in using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

An example for that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script>
    const url = "https://au2mailer.com/api/a2m-getreviews.asp?apikey={{apikey}}";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        let receivedDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        let jsonStr = receivedDom.body.innerText;
        document.write(jsonStr);
        let parsedObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        document.write(parsedObj.totvotes)
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```